# html2canvas creating issue for dynamiclly added divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, html2canvas

I am adding some html from ajax into my existing html. There is already a div which I am eandring into html2canvas by

```
$('#main-frame'+taskNumber).html2canvas({
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
    $('#img_val_'+taskNumber).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
   }
});
```

taskNumber is 1 for starting div. But when I load another div with id main-frame2 it is not able to render and creating error as shown below

```
'doc is undefined'
```

When I debug the object which render, at first it is creating and element but after that it is creating an array so html2canvas not able to render it.